# ¿Por qué no funciona Ajax en mi plugin WordPress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

estoy desarrollando un plugin wordpress para registrar datos de una API, es la primera vez que desarrollo un plugin para wordpress. He avanzado pero ahora tengo un error cuando busco traer la respuesta de una función a través de ajax jquery.

El JS

```
(function($) {

$("#btntest").click(function () {
    alert("OK jQuery");
    console.log("Cargar Datos de Inmueble...");
    testing();
});

$("#btntest2").click(function() {       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            'action': 'check_in',
            'variable': 45 
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert('Respuesta: ' + response);
        },
        error: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });     
});})($);
```

La función de check_in que debe mostrar el mensaje

```
function check_in(){
echo "OK";
die();}
```

La función RUN

```
    public function run() {     
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_in', array( $this, 'check_in' ) );       
    $this->loader->run();
}
```

Enqueue Scripts

```
public function enqueue_scripts() {

     wp_enqueue_script( 'odhkool-admin', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/odhkool-admin.js', array('jquery'), false, true );    
}
```

Cuando doy click en el boton este es el mensaje que trae:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para que tu función responda a la llamada por ajax debes agregarla a la lista de ejecución de funciones ajax con:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_check_in', 'check_in');
```

Referencia [en inglés](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Como el anterior compañero dice, tienes que ponerlo en cola. Yo empleo estos dos hooks:

```
// Hook para usuarios no logueados
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nombre_de_tu_funcion_escrita_en_el_action_del_ajax', 'nombre_de_tu_funcion_escrita_en_el_action_del_ajax');

// Hook para usuarios logueados
add_action('wp_ajax_nombre_de_tu_funcion_escrita_en_el_action_del_ajax', 'nombre_de_tu_funcion_escrita_en_el_action_del_ajax');
```

Y si además empleas la función **wp_localize_scripts()** para la url del ajax será más seguro y limpio.